# Get string value from select UISegmentedControl segment

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I've created a SignUp page (ViewController) and on gender selection I'm using a UISegmentedControl for "male", "female", "indifferent". But how can I get the value from the UISegmentedControl and put in a dictionary? I'm using a custom `Dictionary<String, String> = [:]` for signup but the UISegmentedControl is not a string (obviously) and I get the error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'UISegmentedControl' to type 'String'

How can I convert the result of UISegmentedControl to receive those values?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var birthdayField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmpasswordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var instagramuserField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var generoSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var DatePickerDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signupOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func signupAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if let name = self.nameField.text {
            if let email = self.emailField.text {
                if let birthday = self.birthdayField.text {
                    if let password = self.passwordField.text {
                        if let confirmpassword = self.confirmpasswordField.text {
                            if let instagramuser = self.instagramuserField.text {
                                if let gender = self.generoSegmentControl {

                                    if password == confirmpassword {
                                        print("Senhas iguais, podemos seguir")
                                    }else {
                                        print("As senhas precisam ser iguais")
                                    }

                                    self.auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

                                        if error == nil {

                                            var user: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]

                                            user["nome"] = name
                                            user["email"] =  email
                                            user["nascimento"] =  birthday
                                            user["instagram"] =  instagramuser
                                            user["genero"] = gender



                                            //Encoding email for Base 64
                                            let key = Base64().encodingStringBase64(text: email)

                                            let users = self.database.reference().child("usuarios")

                                            users.child(key).setValue(user)

                                            print("Sucesso ao cadastrar usuário!")
                                        }else{
                                            print("Erro ao cadastrar usuário, tente novamente!")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }else {
                                    print("Escolha seu genero")
                                }
                            }else{
                                print("O campo usuário do instagram esta vazio")
                            }
                        }else{
                            print("As senhas não conferem")
                        }
                    }else{
                        print("Digite uma senha")
                    }
                }else{
                    print("Digite a data do seu nascimento")
                }
            }else{
                print("Digite seu e-mail")
            }
        }else{
            print("Digite seu nome")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func generoAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let genIndex = generoSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex

        switch genIndex {
        case 0:
            print("Homem")
        case 1:
            print("Mulher")
        case 2:
            print("Indiferente")
        default:
            print("Nada selecionado")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can get the index of the selected tab of the segmentedControl right? from that why not you can get the String from the array (or whatever data model) from which you populated the values???

Comment: I think you want titleForSegment(at:) which will return the name of the segment as configure in IB. You should not need a separate dictionary in your code.

Comment: I wouldn't use the title of the SegmentedControl, because it's localized. Instead I'd create an Enum, which has a property/func `localizedTitle()` that returns the localized name, and keep in the dict/model the enum value for the gender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the `segmentedControl` in your code, but not it's `selectedSegmentIndex` property. Then after receiving the selectedSegmentIndex, you should get the title for that index from control. Update your code with following:

```
if let gender = self.generoSegmentControl {
```

Either change it to:

```
let genderIndex = self.generoSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
if let gender = self.generoSegmentControl.titleForSegment(at: genderIndex) {

}
```

OR change the way you update dictionary:

```
let index = gender.selectedSegmentIndex
if let segmentTitle = gender.titleForSegment(at: index) {
    user["nome"] = name
    user["email"] =  email
    user["nascimento"] =  birthday
    user["instagram"] =  instagramuser
    user["genero"] = segmentTitle
}
```

Comment: @emrepun [i getting the error initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'string'](https://i.imgur.com/lxeBADF.png)

Comment: Yeah because, the setgmentedControl is not optional, you dont need if let, just let would be fine. Check the edited answer please.

Comment: @emrepun Nice, that actually works!,  [but in firebase i receive the int value!, how can i get the string? "male", "woman", "Indifferent"](https://i.imgur.com/SFtbLX5.png)

Comment: @PinhaDooido either implementation converts index to a string actually. Can you double check with my answer and your code to see if you are also converting to string?

Comment: @emrepun Your answer converts the selected index to a string but that isn't what the OP wants. The OP wants the label corresponding to the selected index.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, now it gives the title for selectedIndex. Please check updated code PinhaDooido.

Comment: @emrepun Damn your a god!, thanks that's resolved my problem and thank you for being patient this whole time.